# pandas.Dataframe() mixed data types and strange .fillna() behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fillna

I have a dataframe which has two dtypes: Object (was expecting string) and Datetime (expected datetime). I don't understand this behavior and why it affects my fillna().

[image]

Calling .fillna() with inplace=True wipes the data denoted as int64 despite being changed with .astype(str)

[image]

Calling .fillna() without it does nothing.

[image]

I know pandas / numpy dtypes are different to the python native, but is it correct behavior or am I getting something terribly wrong?

sample:

```
import random
import numpy
sample = pd.DataFrame({'A': [random.choice(['aabb',np.nan,'bbcc','ccdd']) for x in range(15)],
                       'B': [random.choice(['2019-11-30','2020-06-30','2018-12-31','2019-03-31']) for x in range(15)]})
sample.loc[:, 'B'] = pd.to_datetime(sample['B'])
```

[image]

```
for col in sample.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist():
    sample.loc[:, col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: str(x).strip().lower()).fillna('NULL')

for col in sample.columns:
    print(sample[col].value_counts().head(15))
    print('\n')
```

Here neither 'NULL' nor 'nan' appear. Added .replace('nan','NULL'), but still nothing. Can you give me a clue what to look for, please? Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is converting missing values to `string`s, so `fillna` cannot working. solution is use pandas function [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) working with missing values very nice:

```
for col in sample.select_dtypes(include='object').columns:
    sample[col] = sample[col].str.strip().str.lower().fillna('NULL')
```

Comment: works great! So when data is loaded all missing values default to np.nan? and then since I changed astype to string it should be noted as 'nan', but .replace('nan','NULL') didn't pick it up, why?

Comment: @BartekMalysz - I see your first comment. Yes, if think `read_csv` function then missing values are `NaN`s. And after testing `sample[col] = sample[col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: str(x).strip().lower()).replace('nan', 'NULL')` it working nice for me with your sample data.

Comment: Every time I go with 'df['col'] = ...' I get warning, so I go with 'df.loc[:,'col']' The thing is, though '.fillna()' always worked alright.